# Single barcode with Code128B and Code128C with iTextSharp

Tags: itext, barcode

I wish to generate a barcode mixing code128B and code128C with iTextSharp DLL. Do you know how to do that ? I currently know only with a single codeset.

By example, I wish to generate a barcode with the value **8L1 91450 883421 0550 001065**
where "**8L1 91450**" is in code128B and "**883421 0550 001065**" is in code128C.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Barcode128` will actually automatically switch from `B` to `C` if and when it can but it sounds like you don't want this. For the control that you're looking for you'll need to set your barcode's `CodeType` property to `Barcode.CODE128_RAW` and manually set the raw values.

There's a [couple](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg12722.html) of [posts](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg35771.html) out there that give the basic idea but unfortunately they tend to assume to much knowledge of iText or too much knowledge of barcodes.

I'm not a barcode expert either but the basic idea is to create a string that starts with `Barcode128.START_B`, then the first part of your text, then `Barcode128.START_C` and then the second. When in raw mode, text isn't ASCII, however. You can use [this site](http://www.barcodeisland.com/code128.phtml) to get the character codes for various ASCII values. But basically instead of sending the letter `L` you'd send `(char)44`.

Hopefully this gets you started at least.